# Google char API table has no columns

Tags: javascript, asp.net-web-api, google-visualization

I'm trying to use Google Chart API in my Aspnet application.
My data is provided by a Web Api controller, I'm using Google.DataTable.Net.Wrapper do generate my data, and the following template in Javascript :

```
    function drawVersionDistributionChart() {
        var versionDistributionJsonData = $.ajax({
            url: BASE_URL + "api/VersionDistribution",
            dataType: "json",
            async: false
        }).responseText;

        // Create our data table out of JSON data loaded from server.
        var versionDistributionData = new google.visualization.DataTable(versionDistributionJsonData);

        // Instantiate and draw our chart, passing in some options.
        var versionDistributionChart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('versiondistribution_chart_div'));
        versionDistributionChart.draw(versionDistributionData, { width: 500, height: 300 });
    }
```

My data seems well formatted :
{"cols": [{"type": "string" ,"id": "VersionNumber" ,"label": "Version number" }, {"type": "number" ,"id": "ApplicationCount" ,"label": "Application count" }], "rows" : [{"c" : [{"v": "1"}, {"v": 1}]}]}

I validated the data with Google API Playground.

I also tried to use the Chart Wrapper method by providing the URL of my Web API controller as datasourceUrl.

What am I missing please ?

Comment: I tested your code with that JSON, and it worked.  Check to see if your data source is actually returning data - visit the `BASE_URL + "api/VersionDistribution"` URL in a browser and post what it outputs.

Comment: Hi, I tested it using firebug, the data returned is : "{\"cols\": [{\"type\": \"string\" ,\"id\": \"VersionNumber\" ,\"label\": \"Version number\" }, {\"type\": \"number\" ,\"id\": \"ApplicationCount\" ,\"label\": \"Application count\" }], \"rows\" : [{\"c\" : [{\"v\": \"V1.0.0\"}, {\"v\": 1}]}]}"

Maybe it has something to do with WebApi ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, there seem to be an issue with the way data is formatted when it is returned by the Web API controller.

Here is what I did to make it work :

Changed the datatype to 'xml' in the ajax method.

```
var versionDistributionJsonData = $.ajax({
            url: BASE_URL + "api/VersionDistribution",
            dataType: "xml",
            async: false
        }).responseText;
```

Removed the XML schema and keywords added by Web API controller :

```
versionDistributionJsonData = versionDistributionJsonData.replace('<string xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/">', '');
versionDistributionJsonData = versionDistributionJsonData.replace('</string>', '');
```

Now it works.